# Jquery css border radius specific corners radius?

Tags: jquery, css

Hello I am trying to change the border-radius of specific corners of some uls with jquery sortable on the method sort.

Here is my code so far and it is not working, any ideas?

```
sort: function() {
    var borderSet = $('#fluidWrap ul:last-child').attr('id');
    if (borderSet == 'sideWrap') {

        $('#sideWrap ul').css({BorderTopRightRadius: 10, BorderBottomRightRadius: 10});
    }
    else {
        $('#sideWrap ul').css({BorderTopLeftRadius: 10, BorderBottomLeftRadius: 10});
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you need not mention units, I say 10px instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use:

```
border-radius: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
```

which is:

```
border-radius: [top-left],[top-right],[bottom-right],[bottom-left];
```

This tool is very good for css3: [css3generator.com](http://css3generator.com/)

Answer (score 6):

try

```
.css({'border-top-right-radius': 10})
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be more helpful to try using the [jQuery corner plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/) as it will also account for browser differences in border radius definitions.

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
css({BorderTopRightRadius: '10px', BorderBottomRightRadius: '10px'})
```